# Safety of bitshift operators on different-width datatypes

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bitwise-and

Bitwise operators have never been my forte.  I'm wondering when explicit casts are necessary when using bit-shifts.

For example, is `i&1 == i%2` guaranteed to be true whenever `i` is an unsigned integer type, e.g. `char`, `unsigned`, `uint64_t` etc.? I think the question is whether the `1` in `i&1` is implicitly casted to a type of width `sizeof(i)`.

As a second example, if I do a `i = 1<<myshift`, do I need to first explicitly cast the `1` to a datatype sufficiently wide to store the shifted result, e.g.: `i = (uint64_t)1<<myshift`?

Is the type of `myshift` in the second example irrelevant as long it's unsigned?

---

I think the answers to these are yes, yes, and yes. The second example in particular can be quickly checked. But does anyone have a good reference for this stuff? Links-to / quotes-from the C standard would be hugely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Yes. The odd bit is the least significant - the one that is on in '1', whatever representation you will choose.

according to [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **Constraints**
>
> 2 Each of the operands shall have integer type.
>
> **Semantics**
>
> 3 The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.
>
> 4 The result of the binary & operator is the bitwise AND of the operands (that is, each bit in
>   the result is set if and only if each of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is set).".

2 Yes, you do have to do this if you need more than `sizeof(int)` bytes (which will probably be 4).

3 Yes. The standard again:

> **Constraints**
>
> 2 Each of the operands shall have integer type.
>
> **Semantics**
>
> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
>   that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
>
> 4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>   zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1*2^E2, reduced modulo
>   one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and E1*2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is
>   the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple as far as I understand it, No - they are talking about the *value* if myshift. not `sizeof(myshift)`. As to 1, do you know any sensible representation in which the odd bit is not the LSB? it is not 1/2s complement anyway.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple - I think I was wrong about the signedness. but it is still a `yes`.

Comment: In (1) I was wondering how `x&y` is defined when `x` and `y` are different widths. Actually it didn't occur to me that 1 might not be the LSB.

Comment: @DouglasB.Staple I tried to elaborate a bit. But really, just look at the standard.